# IIS File Lock - The Process Cannot Access The File Because It Is Being Used By Another Process

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have a text file that contains cached data in JSON format. I'm trying to update the file, but my IIS worker process is locking the file and when I try to write to it, I get the error "The Process Cannot Access The File Because It Is Being Used By Another Process". I've searched for answers on Google and Stack, but I can't seem to find anything related to IIS locking a file. The text file is included in my Visual Studio solution and I am using IIS on my local machine to host my website. For my first question, I'm wondering how I can get IIS to release the file or not lock it at all. For second question, I'm wondering if there's a different approach to prevent IIS from locking my files.

Comment: Can you please post the code that is reading/writing from that file within your application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking a lunch break, I realized that the worker process was hanging on to the text file  because it was reading a line from it and then attempted to write to it. I wrapped the file in a using statement and moved the write after the read and now it's working.

Answer (score 7):

IIS is not locking your file. IIS has no idea your file exists. Some application, probably your own, is locking the file.

Try using a program like [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) from [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/) to find out which process is locking the file.

Comment: ps: you can use the free sysinternals tool, *Handle*, to determine which app has the file locked: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655

Comment: I did use Process Explorer before posting this question to find out which process was locking the file and, as I said in the description, the process which is locking the files is my IIS worker process.

Comment: The IIS worker process is not "IIS". That's _your_ code running in that process.

Comment: My problem was that I was not using the long version of my file stream reader's constructor. It's important to set the file sharing mode (to "share") when you open a file for reading if you know something else is writing to it.

Comment: If such, it's even probably possible to check using the default Windows 10 `Task Manager` -> `Performance` tab -> `Resource Monitor` -> `CPU` tab -> `Associated Handles` and search for a file. Same `Resource Monitor` should exists in other versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (file locked by IIS worker process) when attempting to publish a .NET Core API app.

In case it helps anybody, my issue was caused by a related application, which was calling the API, being in debug mode when attempting to publish the API.

Answer (score -3):

I was able to fix the problem by having the app pool recycle after each request. Go to the Advanced Settings of your app pool. Under Recycling, set request limit to 1.

Comment: This is really inefficient advice. Recycling the application pool causes the worker processes to be restarted. Although there is a (configurable) overlap between the existing worker process and the new worker process, there is a lot of work performed in compiling the application again, which is going to happen after each request in this scenario.